# Show that this integral is finite: $ \int_{\mathbb R^3} e^{-\| x\|^2} e^{- a \| x\| \coth (\| x\|) -\| x\| } \, dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Haw to prove that the following integral
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^3} e^{-\| x\|^2} e^{- a \| x\| \coth (\| x\|)  -\| x\| } \, dx $$
is finite ? where $a>0$.

thanks you in advance

Comment: I forgot a "-" before $a$

Comment: is the exponent in the second exponential $-||x||\left\{1+a\coth||x||\right\}$? If it is, note that $1+a\coth||x||\ge 1$, so the integrand is $\le \mathrm e^{-||x||^2} \mathrm e^{-||x||}$, whose convergence is rather simple to prove.

Comment: @ Accidental FT, you are right, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Your integral is **convergent**.

Potential problems are as $\| x\| \to +\infty$ and as $\coth (\| x\|) \to +\infty$ ($\| x\| \to 0$).

- As $\| x\| \to +\infty$, we have $$
     -\| x\|^2- a \| x\| \coth (\| x\|)  -\| x\| =-\| x\|^2+O(\| x\|) \sim -\| x\|^2 $$ and your integral is convergent since, for some $M>0$, it behaves as $$ \int_{\mathbb R^3 \:\cap\: \| x\|\geq M} e^{-\| x\|^2}dx <\int_{\mathbb R^3} e^{-\| x\|^2}dx <+\infty.$$
- As $\| x\| \to 0$, we have $$    -\| x\|^2- a \| x\| \coth (\| x\|) 
     -\| x\| =-a+O(\| x\|) $$ and your integral is convergent since, for some $\epsilon>0$, it behaves as $$ \int_{\mathbb R^3 \:\cap\: \|
     x\|\leq \epsilon} e^{-a}dx=\int_{\|
     x\|\leq \epsilon} e^{-a}dx <+\infty.$$

Comment: thank you so much for the help

Comment: @Z.Alfata You are welcome.